# Get all data by xpath

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

Webpage have a following code:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <time data-timestamp="1458895194718" title="2016-03-25 11:39:54<small    class="milliseconds">.718</small>">11:39</time>
    </td>
    <td>
     <span class="invisep"><</span>
     <mark class="nickname" style="cursor:pointer;  color:#03DC03">usernickname</mark>
     <span class="invisep">></span>
    </td>
    <td>
      Action
      <a class="help" href="/link=56.280566,43.925091&z=17&pll=76.284566,63.924091" title="City, Country, 999999" onclick="window.selectPortalByLatLng(76.284566, 63.924091);return  false">PointName</a>
    </td>
```

I can find by xpath time (11:39), Action or PointName.
This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import FirefoxProfile

profile = FirefoxProfile('C:\\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\q1bvoou3.default')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.get('https://www.url.com/')
driver.implicitly_wait(20) # seconds
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody').text
print (element)
```

Is there any way to get all data? milliseconds, colors, coordinates and so on.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of `driver`? Can you post a short, complete program that demonstrates your question?

Comment: Sure. Sorry. Post was updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This other information you are looking for is an attribute of different elements in the page.  You would need to get the WebElement for each item of interest, and request the attribute.  For example:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css('mark.nickname')
print (element.get_attribute('style'))
```

will pull out the style of all of the "mark" elements with a class "nickname", for all rows in the table that have this element.  You would then use a regular expression to extract the color from this style.

As another example, the coordinates are inside the method call that's in the onclick attribute of your link:

```
linkelement = driver.find_element_by_css('a.help')
print (linkelement.get_attribute('onclick'))
```

So, you'll have to parse the coordinates out of that method call.

Comment: @AlgarAlg I would appreciate it if you would select this as the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@type='submit']"):
    print (i.get_attribute("value"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Q: Is there any way to get all data? milliseconds, colors, coordinates and so on
First: find_element_by_xpath returns one element if you like to select a list use **find_elements_by_xpath**.

It is not really clear what you are expecting:

To get all text nodes you may try within the tbody:
`//html/body/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody//text()`
But the color seems to be part of the style attribute. To get all attributes you may use:
 `//html/body/div[3]/div[2]/table/tbody//@*`